# assign cdkDrag dynamically to div using Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have a `div` which sometimes need to be draggable and sometimes not, right now it has `cdkDrag` assigned by default, which couses some issues when I don't need it to be draggable.

Is it possible to dynamically add and rmeove `cdkDrag` from div?

Something like:

```
<div [cdkDrag]="isDraggable">...</div>
```

Comment: There's cdkDragDisabled. Have you read the documentation yet and tried it out?

Comment: cdkDragDisabled isn't 100% useful in this specific case